# Git with proprietary code

Tags: git, version-control

Im considering moving from an centralstorage version system to git. How ever I have some concerns of how this will affect sourcecode security? I know version control systems are not really my problem here bur I cant help not to worry about how availability to sourcecode might affect how it is handled by developers? Does any one have experience with this? Are risks of leakage increased when moving to distributed version systems. What do I need to worry about more specifically? And what can be done to keep my source safe?

Comment: Is there away for example to mark repos with the user that checked it out?

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about?  With a centralized VCS your developers still have a complete copy of the code, just not the project history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once someone has a copy of your source code, whether it is git, svn or some high end solution, you always run the risk of someone copying it.  Git does give the person who stole it more history than some other source control solutions.

That being said, we use gitolite and you can use ssh key management to control who can access individual repos and what access controls they may have.  You can also implement hooks on the server to log usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with most of the centralized version control systems, mainly just `svn`.  But at least with that developers would still have access to the entire history of the project by asking the server for it. They could even use `git-svn` to create their own git repository with that history.

Even if there was some version control system that would prevent access to the history, the developers would still need to be able to get a complete copy of the current version which is likely to have the vast majority of the value.

There isn't a way to mark who checked out a copy, and even if there was there wouldn't be anything preventing somebody who wanted to release that code against the owners wishes from removing any such marks.

Answer (score 1):

Security is the same for a distributed VCS as with a centralized one.  Most people run Git as a centralized VCS as well - it definitely lends itself well to this.  The only difference is that version history is available to local clients.

One could add a Hook to check on who is doing what in the repo if it is of grave concern.